# "Now" instead of "from now on" with the future tense

Tags: word-usage, future-tense

A couple of examples first:

- I fixed the tap in the bathroom, **from now on** it won't be dripping.
- I got a new job, **from now on** I'll have to wake up at 6
  AM.
- Our neighbors have left the house so **from now on** they won't bother you.

Can I simplify the highlighted part somehow? It sounds too formal now.
Does that option work?

- I got a new job, **now** I'll have to wake up at 6 AM.

Comment: Yes, you may. Meanwhile, I would use a semicolon for sentences 01 and 02. The two thoughts are independent clauses without conjunctions.

Comment: Thanks, good point about a semicolon. But as for "now", what option works best if I want to avoid it to sound too formal? How would a native speaker build such a sentence?

Comment: "I fixed the tap in the bathroom; it shouldn't drip anymore now." "I got a new job; now, I'll have to wake up at 6 AM." "Our neighbors have left the house, so, from now on, they shouldn't be bothering you anymore."

Comment: I would say that if you want to emphasize the action after the now, I would use, "from now on." And if you just want to emphasize the moment "now," I would just use "now." I would not say it's a matter of formality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between **from now on** and **now** with regards to formal or informal speech but there is a difference in connotation when using them.

When you say **from now on** you are giving a long indefinite period of time - maybe months or years to decades or even longer - and when you are saying **now** you don't indicate any particular time frame but you can only guarantee a very short time.  It could be for a few minutes to maybe a few hours, or it could be a while longer.

With that in mind I would change your examples to

- I fixed the tap in the bathroom; **now** it won't be dripping.
  (You cannot necessarily guarantee an indefinite period of time with mechanical fixes)
- I got a new job; **from now on** I'll have to wake up at 6
  AM.
- Our neighbours have left the house so **now** they won't bother you.
  (The neigbours may only be out for an hour, or may be a little longer).

Comment: The key point in my question was whether it's correct to use now + the future tense. Now it's clear how it works. Thanks.